# Perfect forwarding in the visitor pattern std::visit of C++

Tags: c++, templates, variadic-templates

I was watching Jason Turner C++ weekly and I came across this code snippet.

```
template<typename... B>
struct Visitor: B...{

template<typename... T>
Visitor(T&&...t): B(std::forward<T>(t))...{} 

using B::operator()...;
};

template<typename...T>
Visitor(T...) -> Visitor<std::decay_t<T>...>;

int main(){
    std::array<std::variant<double, int, std::string>, 6> a{3.2, 2, 4, 6, 2.4, "foo"};
    int intTotal = 0;
    double doubleTotal = 0.0;

    Visitor visitor {[&intTotal](const int i){intTotal += i;},
                  [&doubleTotal](const double d) { doubleTotal += d;},
                 [](const std::string& c) { }};

    std::for_each(begin(a), end(a), [&visitor](const auto &v) {std::visit(visitor, v);});
    std::cout << intTotal << " " << doubleTotal << std::endl;
}
```

I can get rid of the the perfect forwarding as well as the deduction guide. Is this  not considered the best practice in C++. In what situations is it less efficient?

```
template<typename... B>
struct Visitor: B...{

  Visitor(const B&... b): B(b)... { }
  using B::operator()...;
};
```

e

Comment: I would turn your question on yourself. Why do you think it is the best practice? Where are you seeing inefficiency in the original?

Comment: With your variation it will simply not work if non-copyable types are involved. Perfect-forwarding is usually best-practice if you are just forwarding arguments.

Comment: I don't see inefficiency in the original, just too verbose and also requires the deduction guide. @Taekahn

Comment: @user17732522 Sorry I am new to this stuff, could you please explain a bit more? I thought in the argument I accept a reference hence no need to copy the argument.

Comment: The constructor's parameter will not cause a copy, but the initialization of the member in `B(b)` will. The answer by @HolyBlackCat gives an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can get rid of the perfect forwarding

Passing by a const reference would copy the lambdas instead of moving them.

It doesn't matter in your case, but it will matter if the lambdas capture things by value. It can hurt performance if the lambdas are expensive to copy, or cause a compilation error if the lambdas can't be copied (because they have non-copyable state, e.g. `[x = std::make_unique<int>()](){}`).

> I can get rid of the ... the deduction guide.

If you pass by const reference, yes. But if you pass by a forwarding reference, no.

The constructor having an independent set of template parameters is one problem. Buf if you used the same template parameters (and inherited from `std::decay_t<B>...` instead), it still wouldn't work, because built-in deduction guides refuse to do perfect forwarding. The template argument deduction wouldn't work if you passed an lvalue.

---

A better question is why have a constructor at all. If you remove it, the type becomes an aggregate and everything continues to work as before.

It even lets you remove the deduction guide (except that Clang doesn't support that yet).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Really enlightening. Indeed it won't compile in clang if I remove the constructor. Why the built-in deduction guide do not work with the perfect forwarding? @HolyBlackCat

Comment: @Amir I'm wondering about that myself.

Comment: @Amir Because the deduction guide would only deduce the types `typename... T`, but there is nothing in the forwarding constructor that could be used to deduce `typename... B`.

Comment: @user17732522 It doesn't work even if you make the constructor non-template, and reuse the class template parameters. Something magical about built-in deduction guides.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat If you replace `T` with `B` in the parameter list, then these won't be forwarding references anymore. But I think it should still correctly deduce from rvalue arguments.

Comment: @user17732522 Only from rvalues though, not from lvalues. That's the question, why they are not forwarding reference for the purposes of deduction. If you manually write the "same" deduction guide, the forwarding will work.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat That's just because a class template parameter cannot form a forwarding reference, also not in the synthesized deduction guide. See the example in https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct#call-3.

Comment: @Amir It is a compilation of the current C++ standard draft. The information there is as close to "official" as you can get without buying the actual standard from ISO. See also https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/links for other links to vital documents.

Answer (score 0):

```
Visitor(const B&... b)
```

All your parameters to this constructor will now be `const` references...

```
                        : B(b)...
```

... and if any of these subclasses' constructors take a corresponding parameter that's a non-`const` reference, this will be ill-formed and not compile.

```
class Foo {

public:
    Foo(int &n) {}
};
```

Try using your visitor with this class, to see if it works. Your template instance's constructor should turn out to be something like

```
Visitor(const int &n) : Foo(n) {}
```

Comment: Only the copy-constructor is used. `b` is a `B`.